# Filter by One to many relation child data

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

## I want to filter by the leadtransactions data (date)

Here i used the transaction details date in leadtransation table.i want to filter by particular date in my leadtransation.Kindly help me with the working sample or the particular code which am gonna write in DAO method.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "lead_master")
public class Lead {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "lead_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
private int lead_id;

@Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
private String first_name;

@Column(name = "last_name")
private String last_name;

@Column(name = "company_name")
private String company_name;

@Column(name = "website")
private String website;

@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

@Column(name = "phone_number")
private String phone_number;

@Column(name = "job_type", nullable = false)
private String job_type;

@Column(name = "date", nullable = false)
private Date date;

@Column(name = "time_stamp", nullable = false)
private Date time_stamp;

@Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
private int status;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "lead_tx_relation", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "lead_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "lead_tx_id"))
private Set<LeadTranscrations> LeadTranscrations;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that in `LeadTranscrations` class you have `transDate` as column attribute

for this

```
private Set<LeadTranscrations> leadTranscrations;
```

you can use query method for this

```
List<Lead> findByLeadTranscrationsTransDate(Date transDate);
```

you can also add order by

```
List<Lead> findByLeadTranscrationsTransDateOrderByTransDateAsc(Date transDate);
```

Comment: What should i do if i want search by role coloum or someother coloum in child table

Comment: you need to create different query methods for every columns

Comment: Could you post some examples.it may be useful for my feature development